# Visual Studio 2008 , Is there a way to embed a product version into MSI package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-installer

I have a solution (sln file) file that contain several projects.

The sln is referring to two projects :

- I have a csharp project that its
  output is an executable assembly ,
  along with configuration file , this
  project has a product version defined
  which increase from time to time.
- I have a project that when i Build it
  , it create an MSI installation
  Package which know how to install the
  other project output in some client
  machine.

Is there a way to embed a product version into the msi package? Can the MSI Package has its own product version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the msi with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(VS.85).aspx) and look at the file table.

[alt text http://blogs.msdn.com/photos/heaths/images/1025520/original.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/photos/heaths/images/1025520/original.aspx)

Comment: Shay: Can the Msi Package has a product version of its own?

Comment: It can, but it will effect many things like major/minor updates.

Comment: Tagid , Verint beherzelya pituach?

Comment: I used to be there, not any more.